# Implementing a progress bar on a database query in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, linq-to-sql

I have a Silverlight application that interfaces with an SQL database. It does this by having a service reference to a WCF service. This WCF service holds a DataContext object (generated by SQLMetal.exe) and accesses the database. The Silverlight application can contact the server to get information, and can submit changes to it etc.

Now, some of the tables contain binary data (images in this case). This may cause the transfer of one of the tables to be relatively slow.

What I would like to have, if at all possible, is a progress bar in the Silveright application which lets the users know about the progress of the transfer.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of these know how long the query will take, nor the percentage complete:  The WCF service, the datacontext, the database.

Your best options are:

- guess the percent complete in the silverlight application
- display an in-progress animation that doesn't indicate when it will complete.

Comment: I echo David's advice: Opting for an animatign "activity" or "waiting" UI element is FAR better than trying to display "progress" which is a VERY hard thing to measure accurately.